# ListView not working after i changed its table. Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

i have created a listview to show all the contents of a database on a screen. the code i am using is this

```
 private void fillData() {
// Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
   Cursor c = datasource.getAllActs();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[] {DataBaseHelper.KEY_DATE,  
    DataBaseHelper.KEY_STEPS,DataBaseHelper.KEY_CALs };
    int[] to = { R.id.code, R.id.Days, R.id.BMI };
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.notes_row, c,  from, to);
   setListAdapter(notes);               
 }
```

which worked beofre with the code below.

```
 private void fillData() {
            // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
            Cursor c = datasource.getAllGoals();
            startManagingCursor(c);
            String[] from = new String[] {DataBaseHelper.KEY_GOAL, DataBaseHelper.KEY_Current,DataBaseHelper.KEY_Target };
            int[] to = { R.id.code, R.id.Days, R.id.BMI };
            SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
            setListAdapter(notes);              
     }
```

i'm just wondering if there is something wrong with this code that i may be missing. i have the logcat if you need it

Comment: Forget the logcat... from your post I can't even tell what the problem is.

Comment: Please post the logcat errors, so we can see what the problem is if Alex didn't guess it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that your new `Cursor` doesn't have a column named `_id`. Make sure that the cursor,

```
Cursor c = datasource.getAllActs();
```

has a column named `_id`, as the `SimpleCursorAdapter` class requires it.

Comment: that is probably the case as  the _ID was not part of the table which gatAllActs(); was accessing.

Comment: Also Alex does having several tables with the same _id field cause any problems

Comment: Nope. In fact, it's often considered good practice to have all of your tables contain an auto-incrementing primary key (i.e. `_id`). Each table's columns are completely independent of any other table's columns. Unless you are doing some sort of complex `JOIN`, there should be no problem at all.

Comment: i kinda thought that when creating the primary key the field name needed to be unique. so i can have 3 tables each with the same primary key with the name  "_id"

Comment: Say you had two tables, `table1` and `table2`, that both had a column called `_id`. Then in SQLite syntax, you'd reference these columns with `table1._id` and `table2._id`, so you see that both are unique. The only restriction is that a table can't contain two columns that both have the same name (obviously).